# I'm looking for help on creating a help site within SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've used SharePoint for all of 23 seconds. I kind of got thrown into it. I'll describe what I have and need and I'm hoping one (or more) of you will know how to point me in the right direction.

**What I have:** 50+ html help files I created. The directory has the html help files in it as well as two folders with images in one and css and javascript files in the other.

**What I need:** I need to put all of that into our SharePoint site and have it work like it did if I were to just open a file in a browser. I was given the impression I could set up a directory structure much like the regular windows directory so that I can throw that all in there and it will all work like it currently does.

**The problem:** I have no idea what I'm doing. I was told to look into creating a library but I'm not sure of the steps or how to set it up.

I'll gladly accept a tutorial link or if you want to walk me through the steps, that'd be awesome(r) too.

Help me Stack Exchange Community, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a document library, open it in Explorer View, drag and drop all of your files into it.  Placing the files in the document library also lets you enable versioning, check-in/check-out, library security, per page security (if needed), workflows, creation/modification metadata, etc..

Comment: I agree, this variant is possibly better. There could be probjems with links to the styles and images, use Style Library in the root web to store it. You also could create assets library to store other resources, such as images. It is possibly to edit content in windows explorer, but do not forget to activate Desktop Experience Feature on the current machine to allow it.

Comment: Is this even a good solution, putting a website in SharePoint like this? Or would a better solution be just to put an accessible internal page that allows you to get to all of the help stuff?

Comment: It honestly depends on your needs.  For example, if this content is meant to be updated over time, then putting it in a document library allows that to be done easily by end users whereas putting it in _LAYOUTS restricts updates to administrators only.  If you are just looking for a place to throw a static website then I would question why it needs to be "in SharePoint" at all.  Simply create a new website in IIS and put it there.

Comment: I had to get SP Designer, but this worked awesome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your HTML pages to them layouts folder on the farm (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS), this is mapping folder, thus you will get access to it by using url like this http://host/_layouts/yourfolder/yourpage.html. If you use relative links inside your html pages, this should work without problems on each web site of your farm, by using mapping folder path, like this http://host/_layouts/yourfolder/yourpage.html or this http://host/subweb/_layouts/yourfolder/yourpage.html or this http://host/subweb/subweb/_layouts/yourfolder/yourpage.html.
Any hierarchy of webs. Just try to do that, if you have access to file system of farm, this is just few minutes work.